# Why internal ORDER BY does not work?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here is the structure of my query:

```
(select @rnk := @rnk + 2 `rank` ,* from table1, (select @rnk := -1) x order by col1)
union all
(select @rnk2 := @rnk2 + 2 `rank`,* from table2, (select @rnk2 := 0) x)
order by rank limit 10
```

According to the results I figured `order by col1` does not work. why?

What I want is: in first, first `select` get sort by `order by col1` and then the final results be alternate by `order by rant`. How can do that?

---

**Edit**: Imagine this results:

```
select @rnk := @rnk + 2 `rank` ,* from table1, (select @rnk := -1) x order by col1

// output: blut, green, red


select @rnk2 := @rnk2 + 2 `rank`,* from table2, (select @rnk2 := 0) x

// output: five, three, one, six, seven, two
```

Now I want this order for the **output:**

```
blue, five, green, three, red, one, six, seven, two
```

But the above query does not work like that. why?

Comment: The first `order by` should work.  Set up a SQL Fiddle and describe what result you intend to get, so we can understand the issue.

Comment: The second `ORDER BY` reorders everything after you combine the two subqueries with `UNION`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Question updated.

Comment: @Barmar yes exactly, so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `order by col1` in another level of subquery:

```
(SELECT @rnk := @rnk + 2 as rank, t.*
 FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY col1) AS t
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := -1) AS x)
UNION ALL
(SELECT @rnk2 := @rnk2 + 2 AS rank, *
 FROM table2
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk2 := 0) AS x)
ORDER BY rank
```

Sometimes doing the ordering in the same query where you assign the `rank` column works, but it's not guaranteed, so it's best to do it in a subquery.

Comment: Thanks, also you missed a closed parenthesis after second `x`. +1

Comment: Also you can remove that `CROSS JOIN`. Because seems useless

Comment: I prefer the ANSI join syntax.

Comment: Yes it is correct, But honestly I'm seeing to use of `CROSS JOIN` in first time as practical, anyway good, +1 *(sorry for poor English)*

Comment: Two short question: if I do that using subquery, the ordering will be guaranteed? and why?

Comment: Yes, it's guaranteed. `ORDER BY` is done **after** calculating the result set for that query. Doing the ordering in a subquery ensure that it's in the correct order before adding the rank column.